# Galleria Fullscreen not working on IE

Tags: php, jquery, drupal, galleria

I'm using Drupal 7 and Galleria 1.2.6 And have got fullscreen theme. My gallery working on Firefox. But when click fullscreen images not working on IE.

Problem line:

```
 this.setStyle(this.get('iefix'), {
```

Full that codes:

```
  if (Galleria.IE) {
            this.addElement('iefix');
            this.appendChild('container','iefix');  
            this.setStyle(this.get('iefix'), {
                zIndex:3,
                position:'absolute',
                backgroundColor: '#000',
                opacity:.4
            })
        }
```

Error log:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0)
Timestamp: Wed, 9 May 2012 13:43:16 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 39
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI: http://mysite.com/sites/all/libraries/galleria/themes/fullscreen/galleria.fullscreen.js
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: What problem ? Show the error log.

Comment: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0)
Timestamp: Wed, 9 May 2012 13:43:16 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 39
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI: http://mysite.com/sites/all/libraries/galleria/themes/fullscreen/galleria.fullscreen.js

Comment: So what is on line 39 of that js file?

Comment: this.setStyle(this.get('iefix'), {

Answer (score 1):

It seems `setStyle` and IE8 are not really working well. There may be a solution [there](http://www.nutt.net/2010/04/02/prototype-js-setstyle-and-ie-not-working-together/)

Shortly it would be to replace the `this.setStyle` with `Element.setStyle`, but you may want to check the `galleria` forum to ensure you got the same version or ask them about this problem.

Comment: @user1213807 you may want to check functions before using them, so around the line `setStyle(this.get('iefix...` you may want to add `if (this.setStyle && this.get) {` but this may break the fix that was done for IE

Comment: Are you sure you don't use a cached js ? Because the if should at least avoid the error. You may try putting an alert or removing the whole if (GALLERIA.IE) block to check that.